# Sendmail: redirect virtuser account to an external email address

Tags: sendmail

anyone knows how to redirect a sendmail virtuser account mail to an external email address?

This is the virtuser table:

```
contact@example.org contact.example.org
```

(In this form the mail to contact@example.org arrives ok to the inbox)

Then I set an alias from:

```
contact.example.org     external@domain.org
```

But doesn´t work... any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use "newaliases" command after editing the alias file ?

Comment: Yes... without success... the email arrives to the linux user account, but not goes out...

Comment: My mistake, it goes perfectly (I mistyped the email alias). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After changes in virtusertable file under `/etc/mail` for sendmail. You need to run below command to take effect in its database file `virtusertable.db`

```
makemap hash virtusertable.db < /etc/virtusertable
```

Then your emails forwarding will be start. Please try it and hope it helps.